# Unexpected result from PostGIS "&&" operator

Tags: postgis

This PostGIS query is unexpectedly returning TRUE:

```
select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-60 -30, -60 -60)', 4326)::geography && ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-30 -30, -30 -60)', 4326)::geography;
```

The vertical lines are 30 degrees apart from one another so I can't visualize a way for the bounding boxes to intersect.

Can someone explain what is happening here?  I would be interested in understanding some PostGIS functions that would produce the projected bounding boxes for future reference.

I'm using PostGIS 3.1.4 in PostgreSQL 13.5.

Comment: Similar question with no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763094/visualize-postgis-geography-bounding-boxes-to-understand-the-operator. Maybe you should write mail to PostGIS users mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/postgis-users.

Comment: I am also getting TRUE on postgres 14.2, postgis 3.3.1.  Seems like a bug